# XCode 4.2 Custom Template Creation?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have to create my own template for Xcode. I am using Xcode version of 4.2.

The custom template must have some groups with some files and classes.

Could you please guide me in this regard.

Thanks,
Easwar

Answer (score 1):

Creating custom project templates in Xcode 4 is difficult and not documented by Apple. If you still want to create a custom project template, read the following article:

[Creating Custom Xcode 4 Project Templates](http://meandmark.com/blog/2011/12/creating-custom-xcode-4-project-templates/)